# How to transfer a site to hosting?

Tags: pages, hosting

I have a website, I made a backup via akeeba backup plugin and placed it on hoststar.ch in the html folder. I always do this and it was always all right, but this time, when I transferred, then all the pages work www.Ddddddd.ch/agenda
www.ddddddd.ch/uuuuu
but when I try to go to www.Ddddddd.ch it shows the default host page "you site is cooming soon" and the like. I can also go to the admin panel. And in the reading settings I have a page that it should display as the main one, but I don’t understand why it shows the default host page

Answer (score 0):

The host often places a default "index.html" file in a public folder such as "www" or "public_html". It's often in the same folder as your root WordPress install and its "wp-config.php" file. If you find and delete it, this should let your WordPress install provide the homepage. (One other option in this case is to update your server config so it looks for "index.php" before "index.html", but usually deleting the file is easier.)

If you're asking specifically about why the Akeeba Backup plugin isn't working as expected, you should contact their support team directly. They likely have documentation on what to do, and how to troubleshoot, in addition to support channels.

If you're asking more generally about moving your site, there are a few things that affect any migration. Number one, there's DNS propagation time. When you change your DNS settings at your registrar to point no longer to the old host, but now to the new host, that takes awhile to take effect. And if you're moving to a completely different domain, it takes time for that new domain to propagate.

Number two, you also have to make sure all the settings are correct. It's not unusual to have to change `wp-config.php` settings when you switch hosts, so you're pointing to the correct database with the right username and password. If you're also switching domains, you'll also need to run a database migration plugin, as the URL gets so embedded in the database in serialized ways that it usually doesn't work to just try to update it manually.

So it would make sense as a first step to contact the specific plugin author and ask them for tips. It may also make sense to reach out to your hosting team to make sure you have all the settings correct. The "coming soon" page sounds more like your DNS settings haven't propagated yet, or perhaps the new host hasn't finalized all the account setup yet.

Comment: dns I changed three hours ago. maybe because of this?I just don’t understand why I can go to the admin panel or write to other pages for example www.Ddddd.ch/agenda

Comment: it just shows the default host page. she is always like that

Comment: It could easily be because you changed DNS so recently. They usually recommend you wait 72 hours - in my experience it's usually between 24 and 48 hours before I can reliably use a new host.

Comment: and here’s why then the admin paneļi works and other pages via slash?

Comment: That sounds more like there is an "index.html" file in your root directory, and you just need to delete it.

Comment: there is no such file :(

Comment: Yes, I had difficulty but found this html file. it turned out he was in the main folder. thanks for the help a lot

Comment: @Kaiser, I added this at the top of the answer - if it did solve your problem please mark as solved :)